# Comparing records to find improvements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 Rails models `Client` and `HealthProfile`:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :health_profiles
end

class HealthProfile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client, optional: true
    scope :start, -> { where(status: 'start' ) }
    scope :end, -> { where(status: 'end' ) }
end
```

`HealthProfile` contains information such as `:panic_attacks` (there are 25 other conditions) and I want to see what percentage of clients show improvement.  To show improvement they would have `panic_attacks: true` in their `:start` `health_profile` and `panic_attacks: false` in their `:end` `health_profile`.  The issue is that `:panic_attacks` defaults to false.

Is there a query I can perform to capture all `clients` that responded true to `:panic_attacks` in their `:start` and false to `:panic_attacks` in their `:end`?  Ideally this solution will work for all 25 conditions.

Comment: Avoid using the word `end` for column names and method names if possible since it requires you to call the method with an explicit reviever to avoid a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do instead is to create a a many to many association and query it:

```
class HealthProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, optional: true
  has_many :panic_attacks
end
```

```
class PanicAttack
  belongs_to :health_profile
end
```

This would let you for example count the number of attacks by using grouping:

```
profile = HealthProfile.find(1)
# this is postgres specific - use the group_date gem if you need something polyglot
per_month = profile.panic_attacks
                   .group("date_trunc('month', panic_attacks.started_at)") 
                   .count
```

And you can also use other sorts of aggregate functions like averages and means to get meaningful stats. For example an imrovement could be a reduction in the count or average length.

Boolean columns are a scurge.

Comment: The only issue is that there are about 25 different conditions.  I was using `:panic_attacks` as an example.  I should've mentioned that in the question.  I will update it now.

Comment: Yeah I suspected that was the case. The same principle applies except you need to generalize it and create a normalization table where you store the condition definitions. There really is no shortcut to actually modeling the domain properly.